# Replacement for FBFriendPickerViewController for Facebook iOS SDK 4

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, friend, facebook-sdk-4.0

According to Facebook v4 changelog, all FB*ViewController were deprecated and we should build our own table view controller to show friends list.

Now, before I put myself working on it, does anyone knows an alternative for FBFriendPickerViewController on Facebook v4?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find one?

Comment: Nope, let me know if you find one.

Answer (score 1):

FBFriendPickerViewController is no longer available in Facebook SDK 4.X onwards

Instead, you have to call Graph API to fetch the friend list:-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/invitable_friends
```

For more information see the  [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/v2.3#step1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already knew that, I put it on the question above. My question is about if anyone built a replacement for that view controller

Comment: The pains you have to go through developing with Facebook, deserve a complete blog...